# Does a digital signature algorithm exist which has a normal, a blind, an elliptic curve and an elliptic curve blind version?

Tags: signature, algorithm-design, blind-signature

**Q:** Does a digital signature algorithm exist which has a normal, a blind, an elliptic curve and an elliptic curve blind version?

I am searching for an algorithm where you can see what happens if you try to transfer it into a blinded or EC version.

There are some algorithms, which have two versions e.g. DSA and ECDSA but is there a single one which has three versions or even all four?

Comment: what do you mean by "blind version" of signature algorithm? Blind signature is a special algorithm, which has specific "interface" and different constructions.

Comment: Regarding elliptic-curve version - I'm sure almost all algorithms which are defined for general groups have EC version. It's just a matter of using EC group instantiation instead of general group.

Comment: e.g. Schnorr blind signature, based on regular Schnorr signature. It has EC version of course (in both cases). But pay attention that Schnorr blind signature has a special interface: a first message "commitment" from signer is required.

Comment: Sorry for answering that late... By blind version I mean a version of an algorithm, where you can see that it comes from a "base" version.  Like Blind RSA comes from RSA because it has kind of the same principle. 
And yes I get what you mean. Basically you're just changing the groups but everything else could be done the same way.
Thx for the Schnorr hint; I'll have a look at it.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with such a family of cryptosystems if you have found one?

Comment: I want to write about it in my thesis and did many research but I just found a lot of  variations which can't even be related to the original algorithm.  It'd be a good example on how you get more security through making an algorithm better (blind version, ec version, ec blind version, etc.)